# Yarn install problem when project folder name has spaces (link is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file)

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, filepath, quotes

When I run `yarn install` in VS Code I get errors because my project is in folder whose name contains spaces.

If I write a command in console manually I can make use of quotes to avoid such problem (like `cd "folder path with spaces"`)

How can I run `yarn install` and other commands if my project folder contains spaces? Maybe I can set some global setting to automatically put quotes around path names?

[image: File path problem]

Comment: don't use spaces in filenames and directories, use `-` or `_`

Comment: @rioV8 thats not a solution. all operating systems allow spaces in file paths thus software running under said OS should account for that. My win username has a space within it, never had an issue until `yarn` / `nodejs`, stop making excuses for buggy software.